# JavaScript EventListener multiple keydown stops after one key triggers keyup

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, keydown

Goodmorning, I'm having trouble with an `EventListener`. I have a keydown event where I check for multiple keys pressed or single press.

**My problem:**
I have three cases: (W + A) - (W + D) or W. After I press the W + A and I release the A key the keyup event is triggered. So logically the keydown event is stopped, but to start the keydown event back up I have to release the W and press it again. Even when the W key is still down after the A key is up the keydown event will not start again.

**My question:**
Is there a way to start the event back up by setting the keydown event to true **or** is there a way that the keydown event recognises a key who is still down without pressing it again.

**Keydown event:**

```
        document.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
            if (!keyStatus) { keyStatus = keyDown(event); }
            if (Object.keys(keysDown).length < 2) {
                keysDown = (keysDown || []);
            } else { Object.keys(keysDown).forEach(k => delete keysDown[k]); }
            keysDown[event.keyCode] = true;
            switch (true) {
                case keysDown[65] && keysDown[87]:
                    if (currentCode.includes(68) || (currentCode.length <= 1 && currentCode.includes(87))) { currentCode = [] }
                    if (currentCode.includes(65) && currentCode.includes(87)) {
                        break;
                    } else { currentCode.push(65, 87); }
                    multiStatus = true
                    break;
                case keysDown[68] && keysDown[87]:
                    if (currentCode.includes(65) || (currentCode.length <= 1 && currentCode.includes(87))) { currentCode = [] }
                    if (currentCode.includes(68) && currentCode.includes(87)) {
                        break;
                    } else { currentCode.push(68, 87) }
                    multiStatus = true
                    break;
                case keysDown[87] && !multiStatus:
                    if (currentCode.includes(65) || currentCode.includes(68)) { currentCode = [] }
                    if (currentCode.length <= 1 && currentCode.includes(87)) {
                        break;
                    } else { currentCode.push(87) }
                    break;
                default:
                    multiStatus = false
                    break;
            }
        });
        document.addEventListener("keyup", event => {
            if (keyStatus) { keyStatus = keyUp(event); currentCode = []; multiStatus = false }
        });
```

I hope someone is able to help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to `keydown` on W to trigger continuously after A has been released?

Comment: Not entirely (but same thought.) Some back story it is movement for s car. So with W you'll accelerate and with A & D you'll steer. So when I lift A or D I want the keydown event to continue.

Comment: @Teemu I hope that some that's enough to work with

Comment: Yes, I suppose so. I think you need totally a different approach. Store the keydowns in properties of an object, and remove the property/set it false when a keyup occurs. Then use a separate "main loop" (interval or preferrably `requestAnimationFrame`), and in that loop, use the existing/truthy properties from the object the events are stored.

Comment: Do you think you can put this as an answer. I think I get it, but it's a little bit vague in my head right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backing up events is, if not impossible, but extremely hard and time-consuming. Instead, register the keyevents separately, create a "main loop" for reading the registry (and for doing other actions). The below snippet isn't a direct solution fitted to your code, instead it introduces the keypress registry and the main loop in a simple example of how to steer an element on the screen.

```js
const ball = {
  a: 0,
  d: 0,
  w: 0,
  z: 0,
  speed: 2,
  posX: 0,
  posY: 0,
  el: document.querySelector('.ball')
}

function regKeyStrokes(e) {
  if (!'adwz'.includes(e.key)) {return;}
  ball[e.key] = (event.type === 'keyup') ? 0 : 1;
}

function animate() {
  const dX = ball.a * -ball.speed + ball.d * ball.speed;
  const dY = ball.w * -ball.speed + ball.z * ball.speed;
  const cS = (dX * dY === 0) ? 1 : 0.707;
  ball.posX += cS * dX;
  ball.posY += cS * dY;
  ball.el.style.transform = `translate(${ball.posX}px, ${ball.posY}px)`;
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

document.addEventListener('keyup', regKeyStrokes);
document.addEventListener('keydown', regKeyStrokes);

requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

```css
.ball {
   position: fixed;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   background: red;
   border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="ball"></div>
```

In the snippet, the key registry is a part of `ball` object (this can of course be a separate object). The properties in the register are named by the used keys. The key strokes and releases are listened independently from the main loop, and the key registry is kept up to date with the listener of these two events.

Comment: Thanks! This works the way I wanted it. The answer is accepted and upvoted.